# Generate barCode and send e-mail in pdf

Tags: laravel

I'm using the milon / Barcode Library to generate barcodes and I need to get this code and send it by email in a pdf using phpmailer.

When I use echo in the barcode, the code appears perfectly on the screen, but in the pdf only the html code of the boleto is returning.

```
           $d = new DNS1D();
            $d->setStorPath(__DIR__.'/cache/');
            $codigo = intval($body->codigoDeBarra);
            $codigobarra = $d->getBarcodeHTML($codigo, 'EAN13',6,50);

            $layout = 'ticket<br>'.$codigobarra;

            $pdf = new TCPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->Write(1, $layout);

            $pdf->Output('/opt/lampp/htdocs/site/public/boletos/cobranca/'.$email.'-'.$datavencimento.'.pdf', 'F');


            // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'host';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'email';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'password';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    $local = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/site/public/boletos/cobranca/'.$email.'-'.$datavencimento.'.pdf';
    //Recipients
    $mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($local), 'cobranca.pdf');
    $mail->setFrom('contato@site.com', 'Bank');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $nome);     // Add a recipient

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Account';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi';

    $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Mpdf Library when using barcodes. It has a reserved working functionality for what you want to acieve.Here's the link https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/barcode.html